# Splitting a 50 Ω pulse signal into two gain stages

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

Given a pulse from a charge-sensitive preamplifier with 50 Ω, output impedance I'd like to split the signal into two separate conditioning circuits.

Using an [AD8009](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8009.pdf) as a buffer I've come up with this circuit. Is this a reasonable way to split the signal, or should some other passive components be added between the AD8009 and the [EL5263](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/el5162-el5163-el5262-el5263-el5362-datasheet?r=494971)?

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, but does AD8009 really work without any DC bias path for the non-inverting input?

Comment: @user287001 I combed through the data sheet and saw no mention. I just followed their application example.

Comment: The datasheet you linked doesn't specify any +input bias current. I guess it's an error. There's printed accidentally bias voltage instead. I guess there should be printed "typically 50uA bias current". In the linked datasheet every example has the DC bias current path. The most common path is about 50 ohm resistor.

Comment: @user287001 I'm a layman, so excuse my ignorance. Are you referring to the resistor in series with the output?

Comment: Let's make this short. I'm sure resistor R1 (=50 ohms) should be between the pin 3 of U6 and the circuit GND to make the +input to have the biasing DC current path for the internal transistor of the IC. So, move the top end of R1 from the input J2 to the pin 3 of U6.

Comment: (continued) Your layman-comment rises other suspections. How the operating voltages of the EL5263 opamps are decoupled? What's the stray capacitance and inductance of the trimpots? Audio frequency trimpot is useless. What about the signal leak from the outputs through the switches to the opamp input? How the switches are wired? BTW you ask are any parts needed to be inserted to the output of AD8009. I'm afraid the problem is how to avoid such parts to be created by poorly designed circuit board and too low spec components.

Comment: @user287001 EL5263 is decoupled with 10uF caps and 4.7ohm resistor in series with supply rails. This is not intended to be a commercial product and I am quite aware it is not the most optimal design. That is exactly why I am asking for advice.

Comment: We do not know how sharp pulses you have and how much you allow them to be distorted. Tell something of it. Do you have proper simulating models for your opamps? Simulation tells how your drawn circuit works if there's no errors caused by the non-idealities of the circuit board and  other passive parts. I'm afraid 1kOhm trimpot doesn't suppress enough the high frequency ringing caused by resonances in the circuit board. You should make some tests with real circuits. 150 ohms  may be better. Feedback with mechanical switches in high frequency application sounds very unsure.

Comment: @user287001 The input pulses are ~10 ns rise time and ~100 us decay. I have modeled the circuit in LTspice and it seems to work fine. Why I am asking on here is because I'm aware of the non-ideal nature of PCBs compared to simulations. I have already made PCBs that include a single stage, including the 1k pot and have no issues with the signal conditioning in terms of degradation. No ringing, just clean gaussian pulses coming from the output.

Comment: 10ns is not especially fast. Have a large contiguous ground plane and keep signal wires max. 20 millimeters long, then there's no need to design anything as matched transmission lines, 1kOhm loading eats well all ringing off. Have, say 1ns rise time and a 10 cm wire => a ringing mess except if there's a properly designed and terminated transmission line.